# How do I remove burdock from my yard?

Tags: weed-control

I have all of this burdock growing and I can not seem to remove them effectively. What should I be doing to remove it?

I have already dug some of them up and that worked but what are my other options?

Comment: [Burdock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctium)?

Comment: dig it up, and eat it.

Comment: @black thumb. Are you for real? do not know how I should be feeling about that!

Comment: Yes, I am. whole foods sells it. Google it for information.

Comment: I did look it up and I see what you mean, thank you for that. Now I wonder, is it good tasting? :)

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you mean [burdock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctium). I don't find them all that much trouble if I put the least effort into them - only if I ignore them for too long do they become a problem - there are much worse weeds.

Burdock is a biennial, which means you have  whole year where you can just cut the tops off and they will never make a flower stalk and the annoying burrs. If you learn to spot them in the first year, you also have a much better chance of pulling up the whole root while it's small. In the second year, if you keep cutting off and composting the leaves, and any incipient flower stalk, they will eventually give up. They are large plants, which means that even a dense patch of them is a finite number and can be dealt with, and produces a satisfying amount of compostable material (which does not turn into more burdock, so long as you don't let it go so long that you have burrs.)

While you can go to the bother of trying to dig out the whole root, repeated pulling or cutting the leaves for compost or mulch is much easier, and beneficial to the compost/garden. You just can't ignore them for a month or more without risking burrs.

Comment: Yes I mean burdock, thank you for the correction. And I will be cutting them down then, thank you for the advice!